# Could not reach external www. Host is not querying for A record, because the domains matches

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain, active-directory

Have a problem where i could not reach my external www as i created company domain with the same name.

I can reach external site from all other locations, but not from my domain, because domain name matches and host is not even requesting A record from DNS.

What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your domain to respond to this external www. If you want to be resolved only from inside you can use **split DNS**.

Regards